# Xcodebuild Log inconsistency

Tags: jenkins, xcodebuild

I recently had to Upgrade our Jenkins CI server and to prove that it did not affect the builds I did a comparison on a build before the update and a build after the update both with the same codebase. I was surprised to see differences other than temp files, date, build numbers etc, it looks like everything happened but some of the cleans/compiles were in different orders. Surprised by this I did another build and did the comparison between the 2 post upgrade builds, again same codebase. And there were similar differences. In all cases the build was a success and I suspect there isn't any issue lurking. But my QA folks are not going to be happy since I can't say conclusively that it is the exact same thing.

Has anyone done a comparison like this before on Xcodebuild logs and seen similar results? And is there a way to ensure a consistent order of cleans/compiles(for the future comparisons)?